# Google plus share set custom caption, description, image and not use og meta

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'm just programming a quiz in js, thus I want to share the results. However since every user gets a custom result I want to share this custom caption, description and image and not the information from og meta.

For facebook works:

```
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        href: href,
        name: quiz,
        caption: caption,
        description: des,
        message: message,
        picture:img,
    }, function(response){});
```

I'm looking for something similar like this for google plus.

Anyone nows anything? Or is this not possible by now? I really appreciate your help

Comment: same here , anybody have answer

Answer (score 1):

Google+ pulls the post details from the URL, you will have to create a custom page for every quiz result that gets shared.

Comment: I thought so :( I dislike this. However it seems to me that facebook is going the same way with it's new sharer 2.0. Maybe I really need to make extra pages for every result. For now facebook is working. g+ is not yet relevant to users so its not a huge drawback not to implement it.

Comment: You don't do it in Google+, you do it on your own website.